# How to Express the Equation of an Ellipse in Canonical Form in Standard Form

Tags: conic-sections

I have an ellipse expressed as $(a+1)x^2+2abxy+(1+b)y^2=r^2.$ I found its center to be $(0,0).$ How can I express this in standard form $\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}=1$ in the $xy$ plane?

Comment: Try rotating the axes and shifting the origin.

Comment: $(b+a+2+\sqrt{(4a^2+1)b^2-2ab+a^2})x^2/2+(b+a+2-\sqrt{(4a^2+1)b^2-2ab+a^2})y^2/2-r^2=0,$ which is not an ellipse for all $a,b.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks for the help. Could you tell me when it may fail to be an ellipse. What should I test?

Comment: Try $a=b=2$ and $r=1$ in e.g. geogebra.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Ok I see what you mean. Could you pls add some steps on how you arrived at your solution. Its the form I wanted.

Comment: If you have an hour, watch this linear algebra [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MN4kSpt6Emc).